# Ajax post to php fails somehow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var feed = $("#instagramFeed .wrap");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST"
        url: "<?= path("instagram_feed.php"); ?>",
        data: { feed_url: "http://iconosquare.com/feed/test", instagram_url: "http://instagram.com/test", $cache_file: "feed.txt" },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
            feed.html(data).find("img").show();
        }
    });
});
```

instagram_feed.php :

```
function getInstagramFeed($feed_url, $instagram_url, $cache_file) {
 //bla bla bla
}
    $feed_url = $_POST['feed_url'];
    $instagram_url = $_POST['instagram_url'];
    $cache_file = $_POST['cache_file'];

    echo $feed_url;

    getInstagramFeed($feed_url, $instagram_url, $cache_file);
```

Can someone help me figure out whats wrong? The script works if I call the functions with preset values, seems to be wrong with the ajax request.

If I do `getInstagramFeed("http://example.example", "http://example.example", "cache_file");` it works

Comment: forgot to add comma after type:post

Comment: Also, `$cache_file: "feed.txt"` should be `cache_file: "feed.txt"`

Comment: Thanks. I feel stupid. lol

Comment: @Regent Can I ask for one more question? 
Right now I preset the values like such: data: { feed_url: "http://iconosquare.com/feed/test", instagram_url: "http://instagram.com/test", cache_file: "feed.txt" },

However, If I want to pass php variables like: feed_url: $variable, how would I do?

Comment: @Codehiker just as you have described: `var x = "url";` and later `{ feed_url: x }`